# What is the performance impact of Atomic Operations in a compute shader?

Tags: c++, opengl, textures, atomic, compute-shader

I have a compute shader which modifies texels in a 256x256 texture.

The compute shader has 256x256x256 invocations where the x and y component of the invocation directly maps to the u and v coordinates of the texel. So each texel could be written to 256 times.

I want each invocation of the compute shader to check what is currently in the given texel and perform some tests to decide whether to overwrite it or not. However to avoid the concurrency problem of them all getting the texel value before any other invocation has written to it I am looking to use an atomic operation to write values to the texture.

However I've been informed that this defeats the point of parallelising the operation as atomic operations force everything else to wait until it is finished, meaning each z invocation of the compute shader will have to go in sequence as they wait for the previous one to atomically write to the texture.

Is this the case and if so how much will this affect performance? It is worth noting that the z invocation can change and could be a lot more than 256

Comment: Atomics in a CUDA environment serialize all reads/writes and all the warps will have to run sequentially. That usually defeats the purpose of parallelism but it's for a greater good. Not sure if the same applies to your case but I guess it does.

Comment: Thanks, I don't suppose you know how else I could fix this concurrency problem? So basically all the invocations check whats in the texture but they all do that at the start so they all read 0 and blindly put their value in